# How to find and rename a batch of files in linux

Tags: linux, bash, find, rename

when using the following command:

```
find foo/bar -type f -name '*.txt' -execdir sh -c 'mv "$0" "new_prefix_${0}"' {}\;
```

I get the following error:
mv: cannot move './abc.txt' to 'new_prefix_./abc.txt': No such file or directory

The './' is the problem, how can I avoid this?

Comment: `"new_prefix_${0#.*/}"` but then you might end up with just one file in each directory. You need a loop.

Comment: It's not clear to me **where** you want to move the files to, i.e. how the resulting mv command should look like. Aside from this: Did you consider using  `rename` instead of `find`+ `mv`?

Comment: just got the answer, thank you all for pitching in!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find foo/bar -type f -name '*.txt' -execdir sh -c 'mv "$0" "new_prefix_$(basename "$0")"' {} \;
```